# Laplace equation for cylindrical rods

Tags: differential-equations, boundary-conditions

I have a system of four cylindrical rods with a certain radius, length, and separation. I have applied different voltages to the rods.[image] I want to solve the Laplace equation, but I am unable to give proper boundary conditions. How to give boundary conditions when the electrodes are cylindrical?

Comment: `but I am unable to give proper boundary conditions` before you worry about boundary conditions, you need to show what the boundary itself is. Laplace is define in closed region. So what is the region you are trying to solve the PDE on? You just drew 4 cylinders. Actually it is not clear if this is a 2D or 3D. I see 4 circles above?

Comment: These are cylinders, I drawn circles so when I project them in 3D, these will become rods of some definite length. And regarding the boundaries, I can place a cubical box of large dimensions so that potential there is zero, but I want to solve for space within the rods.

Comment: Very unclear problem description.

Answer (score 1):

I presume that you want to compute the electrical potential *around* the rods subject to Dirichlet conditions equal to $V_1$ and $V_2$ on the boundaries of the rods and with asympotical boundary conditions $0$ "at $\infty$". As you mentioned, the latter can be approximated by Dirichlet conditions $0$ on the boundary of a large bounding volume.

```
R = 100;
r = 1;
a = -11;
b = 11;
R = DiscretizeRegion[
   RegionDifference[
    Disk[{0, 0}, R],
    RegionUnion[
     Flatten@Table[Disk[{x, y}, r], {x, {a, b}}, {y, {a, b}}]]
    ],
   MaxCellMeasure -> 0.5
   ];

V1 = 1;
V2 = -1;
U = NDSolveValue[{
    Laplacian[u[x, y], {x, y}] == 0,
    DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == V1, a - r <= x <= a + r && a - r <= y <= b + r],
    DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == V2, b - r <= x <= b + r && a - r <= y <= b + r],
    DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == 0, x < a || x > b || y < a || y > b]
    },
   u,
   {x, y} \[Element] R
   ];

Plot3D[U[x, y], {x, y} \[Element] R, PlotRange -> {V1, V2}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, Henrik, the potential on the rods remains constant within the rods, could you please explain how you used this fact that potential is same on each rod. i.e. in region of the first electrode, say defined by (x-2)^+(y-2)^2=4. And the boundary you used       a - r <= x <= a + r && a - r <= y <= b + r.

Comment: @KarmalKumar I suggest thay you look up `DirichletCondition` in the documentation. That should explain everything.